# Why is XPATH (Java 7) selecting too many nodes?

Tags: java, xpath, plist

I have a rather simple plist XML. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>cast</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Michael Boatman</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Dillon Casey</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>directors</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Jace Alexander</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So the XML contains two cast members, and one director.
My XPATH expression is like this:

```
"/plist/dict[key='directors']/array/dict/string/text()"
```

This expression fetches all three records. Why is this the case? I tried numerous more complicated expressions (like dict/key[name()='director']/../), but it always results in the same. 
It fetches three records when I query for "directors" or "cast", and zero records when I query for another string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level `dict` element contains a subelement `key` with value `directors`. Therefore it, and consequently all its three `array` children, are legitimately selected by your XPath expression.

You should instead select

```
/plist/dict/key[text()='directors']/following-sibling::array[1]
```

Comment: I suspected that it was some fundamental misunderstanding on my part. Many thanks!